# How to dynamically add points to a polygon

Tags: c#

I am creating a game in which the barriers I'm creating that are polygons deteriorate based on where they were hit. I am wondering how I can dynamically add points to the polygon as it normally takes an array and I don't want to have to set every point in the array but rather change them when hit. Can you use lists to draw polygons is basically what I'm getting at?

```
 e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.White, BarrierArray1);
```

Comment: The List class has ToArray method. Using this just as you're about to draw the polygon may do the job.

Comment: Yes you can, both use then with a pointList.ToArray() in the drawPolygon call and to insert points at any spot in the list..